# jQuery Add Class on Clicked Tab and Remove When Not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, tabs

I have 3 tabs namely Monthly, Bi-monthly and Weekly. When the user sets one from the list as his default payroll period, that tab would be active. I achieved it by doing this inside the `<script>` tags:

**PHP in script tags:**

```
<?php if ($session['period_type'] == "Monthly") { ?>
    $(".monthly").addClass("active"); 
    $(".monthly a").addClass("active-li");
    // $(".bi-monthly a, .weekly a").removeClass("active-li");
    // $(".bi-monthly, .weekly").removeClass("active"); 
<?php } else if ($session['period_type'] == "Bi-monthly") { ?>
    $(".bi-monthly").addClass("active"); 
    $(".bi-monthly a").addClass("active-li");
<?php } else if ($session['period_type'] == "Weekly") { ?>
    $(".weekly").addClass("active");
    $(".weekly a").addClass("active-li");
<?php } else { ?>
    // $(".monthly").removeClass("active");
    // $(".bi-monthly").removeClass("active");
    // $(".weekly").removeClass("active");
<?php } ?>
```

Below the above code is the following, where I have an ajax call which is not related to this question and two lines of script where `active-li` class is added when a certain tab is clicked and then removed when not:

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#nav ul .monthly").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=payslip/monthly',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#monthly', type:'POST'});
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('An error occured!');
            alert('Error in ajax request');
        }
    });
    $("#nav ul .monthly a").toggleClass("active-li");
    //$("#nav ul .monthly a").removeClass("active-li");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.active-li {
    color: rgb(65, 202, 191) !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

There. So when I click a tab, the style is changed BUT when I click another one, the previous tab that I clicked remains styled, when it's suppose be back to its original look. That previously clicked tab would only change back to its original style when I click it back.

Something is wrong with my code. Hope someone can help.

**EDIT** I updated my code. But still the same problem.

Comment: did you try removing `.not(this)` on the last part of your code? then change the sequence.. remove the `active-li`'s first then add the active li

Comment: I just removed it. but didn't answer my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add to the "success" function of the ajax call the lines:

```
$(".bi-monthly a, .weekly a").removeClass("active-li");
$(".bi-monthly, .weekly").removeClass("active");
```

In fact, you could also move the addClass calls to that function, rather than generate them in PHP. You would have to ensure that the ajax call returns a success status if and only if in PHP:

```
if ($session['period_type'] == "Monthly")
```

Likely this is already the case.